# Convert string to dictionary while adding values together for identical keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dataset of names and activities. This data is in one long string format. The data is divided into multiple lines (separated by line break "\n"). Each line has a name and an activity separated by a colon. The last line does not have the line break.

Example: `"Jack:travel\nPeter:cycling\nJack:fishing\nPeter:running"`

The goal is to create a dictionary from this string, but if names are duplicates, then add activities together into a list after this name:

In the current example the output should be:

```
{"Jack": ["travel", "fishing"], "Peter": ["cycling", "running"]}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Can you add your current code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Each line specifies a one-key dict, which can be merged using techniques from the linked duplicate (which includes merging them into the desired result, one at a time, as they are processed in a loop).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can just use `str.split()` to loop over every line, then get the name and activity, adding or appending them depending on whether or not it is already in the dictionary. Like this:

```
data = 'Jack:travel\nPeter:cycling\nJack:fishing\nPeter:running\nJack:fishing'

dic = {}
for line in data.split('\n'):
    [name, activity] = line.split(':')
    if name not in dic:
        dic[name] = [activity]
    elif activity not in dic[name]:
        dic[name].append(activity)

print(dic) # => {'Jack': ['travel', 'fishing'], 'Peter': ['cycling', 'running']}
```

However, as a comment pointed out, it may be better to use a set that will automatically drop duplicates. Like this:

```
data = 'Jack:travel\nPeter:cycling\nJack:fishing\nPeter:running\nJack:fishing'

dic = {}
for line in data.split('\n'):
    [name, activity] = line.split(':')
    if name not in dic:
        dic[name] = {activity}
    elif activity:
        dic[name].add(activity)

print(dic)
# => {'Jack': {'travel', 'fishing'}, 'Peter': {'cycling', 'running'}}
```